# How to change a particular div background color along with open a new page by clicking a linkbutton?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net web application..

In that I have a linkbutton in a `div` element. when I click link button I want to open a new page and change div elements background color to be changed at the same time. I tried to assign a clickevent in code behind and button click event in page load. It only opens a new page. no `div` background changed.

Code:

```
protected void LBHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        menuHome.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF00FF");

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

LBHome=LinkButton.
menuHome=div Class name.

Code-BEHIND:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LBHome" runat="server" Font-Overline="False" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" OnClick="LBHome_Click" EnableTheming ="True">Home</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Post your code as well please.

Comment: If you have the new tab URL on your web page, create a javascipt function instead of postback.
But if you want to do it from backend code, post your html and back-end code so someone can help you.